# error in name for ng-repeat dynamic name how to make it dynamic

Tags: angularjs

```js
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

        <script>
        
var app = angular.module('year', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  
    $http.get("year.php")
   .then(function (response) {
    $scope.years = response.data.years;
   
   var ids = [];
   var havedata = [];
   
  for ( var i = 0 ; i < $scope.years.length; i++) { 
    
  ids.push($scope.years[i]["id"]);
    
    $http.get("book.php?id="+$scope.years[i]["id"]+"").then(function (response) {
  
            books = response.data.yearbooks ;
        
        
              if (response.data.yearbooks.length == 0 )
              {
                var check = 0 ;
                    for(var t = 0 ; t < ids.length ; t++)
                    {
                        for(var n = 0 ; n < havedata.length ; n++)
                        {
                         
                        if(ids[t] == havedata[n])
                        {
                            check = 1 ;
                        
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            check = 0 ;
                            
                        }   
                        }
                        if (check == 0)
                        {
                            
          $scope["yearbook"+ids[t]]  = response.data.yearbooks ;
                           
                        }
                    }           
              }
              else
              {
                
          $scope["yearbook"+books[0]["year"]]  = response.data.yearbooks ;
         console.log(books[0]["year"]);
            havedata.push(books[0]["year"]);
 
              }
   });
}
           console.log($scope);
  
 
   });
});

</script>
```

```html
  
     <div class="panel-group" id="accordion2" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true" 
                     ng-app="year" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
  <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="y in years" >
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo"  >
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapse11{{ y.id }}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse11">
       {{ y.Name }}
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse11{{ y.id }}"  class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading22">
    
      <div class="panel-body"  >
    
      <ul >
      
      <li ng-repeat="x in yearbook">
     {{ x.Name }}
      </li>
      
      </ul>

  

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   
   
</div>
```

**How make my yearbook in `<li ng-repeat="x in yearbook">` dynamic to get values  **

> I think the error in this point but i don't know how to solve it

```
 <li ng-repeat="x in yearbook">
```

[this is the success output when i change yearbook to yearbook3]

[when i change yearbook to yearbook3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPKEA.png)

**what i must do please help me**

Comment: You do not have a `$scope.yearbook`. From what it appears you have some number of `$scope.yearbook#`

Comment: yes , and {{y.id}}  have the values that yearbook take and when i put this i get error , <li ng-repeat="x in yearbook{{y.id}}">

Comment: Your code is too complex ... Also, I dont know what is in your php file. It would have been better you posted a simpler code around your problem.

Comment: ok sorry :( can just help me  , {{y.id}} gives some values and all i need to add this values to array name in ng-repeat="x in yearbook"

Comment: Bro ... as far I think ... you must get updated json from php file, not just the added value. You have to store any new value to php, and get the updated json from there ... rather than adding the new 'key':value on the fly to the $scope.xyz object.

Comment: ok :) thank you i will try again